# make alias available in sub-shells - UNIX

Tags: bash, unix, alias

How can I make all alias listed in 
    ~/.alias 
available in all sub-shells? I am new to unix so I don't know much about this.

Thanks

Comment: Hope the response in this link helps: http://superuser.com/questions/319538/aliases-in-subshell-child-process

Comment: You should prefer functions over aliases anyway. Among their many other benefits over aliases, functions can be exported, i.e. Inherited by subprocesses.

Answer (score 0):

In your home directory there needs to be a `.bashrc` file   You probably have one. For each alias add one line that looks like this:

```
alias[space]myalias[nospaceshere!]=[nospaceshere]'/path/to/command arg1 arg2 '
```

Example:

```
alias ll='ls -l '
```

You can add a trailing space if you feel one may prevent problems in the use of your alias.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu, you can write in ~/.bash_aliases:

. ~/.alias

Every time you open a new terminal, your aliases are defined.